# hide personalization tab for non admin users in aem

Tags: aem

Am trying to Hide some tabs in AEM Page Properties dialog.

However i can hide my custom tabs using rep:policy. 
but,
How to hide OOTB personalization tab in page properties of a page for **non admin users** in AEM?

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent use-case for [Granite Render Conditions](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/docs/server/rendercondition.html). I explained how they work and have an example and some resources in this [blog](https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2019/01/03/how-to-show-hide-page-properties-based-on-page-template-in-aem-6-4/).

> using an ACL policy won’t work here, because even if you overlay the tab, the sling resource merger will still find the tab under /libs.

So here are the steps you need to do:

1. Overlay the personalization page properties tab
2. Follow the blog, create a new render condition, then in the logic, check if the current user is in the “administrators“ group.

I think this should very straightforward. but if you’d like a working example, I can provide one today/tomorrow.

Comment: My thoughts exactly

Comment: Do you happen to know if render-conditions can be used within ClassicUI, as well as in "TouchUI"?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do overlay which is always an overhead then you can do the followings :

1. Write a servet to check user is admin or not

   ```
   @Component(name = "com.aem.showcase.core.impl.AdminUserCheck", 
   service = Servlet.class, property = {
   "service.description=Admin user check", 
   "sling.servlet.methods=GET",
   "sling.servlet.paths=/bin/isadminuser" })

   public class AdminUserCheck extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet{
   protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, 
   SlingHttpServletResponse resp)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
   resp.setContentType("application/json");
   resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

   Session session = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
   boolean isAdmin = Boolean.FALSE;

   UserManager um;
   try {
       um = AccessControlUtil.getUserManager(session);
       User currentUser = (User) um.getAuthorizable(session.getUserID());
       isAdmin = currentUser.isAdmin();

       JSONWriter jsonWriter = new JSONWriter(resp.getWriter());
       jsonWriter.object();
       jsonWriter.key("isadmin").value(isAdmin);


       jsonWriter.endObject();
   } catch (RepositoryException | JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

    }
   }
   ```
2. Create a clientlibs under /apps/your-project/and add categorisation as “cq.personalization.wizard“
3. Add the below code

   ```
    (function ($) {
   'use strict';

    $.getJSON('/bin/isadminuser', 
   function(data) {
        if(!data.isadmin){
           $( "coral-tab-label" ).each( function( index, element ){
               if($( this ).html() === 'Personalization'){
                   $( this ).closest("coral-tab").hide();
               }
               });
      }
    });
    }(jQuery));
   ```
4. Finally add extraClintLibs property to your page which is "cq.personalization.wizard". You need to add this under your project structure, I am taking we-retail as an example : /apps/weretail/components/structure/page/cq:dialog